# Why use ImageDrawable Property image size is very short in ImageView Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation, android-drawable

i use ImageDrawable for display image in ImageView Widget,But this Image is Very short.
when I use ImageResource Property size is okay

My code
ImageResource:

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.a1);
```

My code
ImageDrawable:

```
imageview.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.a1);
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: First of all what size of the ImageView? And try to change scale type of ImageView.

Comment: size imageview is Wrap_content

Comment: What size of your 'a1' image (px)?

Comment: I Could Resolve Problem.I use LayoutParams for change Size of Images

Answer (score 1):

You can use BackgroundDrawable for ImageView

```
imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.a1);
```

Comment: thanks for answer,but BackgroundDrawable not work and do similar setImageDrawable